# How to test an asynchronous JavaScript function: Promises, Jasmine, PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm trying to set up a unit test for a function that retrieves data from a server. I want to test that expected data is being returned by the function. Here's the function:

```
getData: ->

    url = api.getURL "data"
    fetch url
```

Now I'm using fetch to get the data, so that returns a promise, so I would use that function like this:

```
@getData()
.then (response)->
  response.json()
.then (data) ->
  //do stuff with 'data'
```

I'm running unit tests using Karma with Jasmine and PhantomJS. PhantomJS doesn't currently support fetch or promises so I'm using polyfills (isomorphic fetch and Q). This is how my test suite is looking:

```
fetch = require "isomorphic-fetch"
Q = require "q"

describe "Module", ->

  myModule = require "./module.coffee"

  it "should get data", ->
    dfd = Q.defer()
    promise = dfd.promise
    spyOn(window, "fetch").and.callFake ->
      promise

    dfd.resolve
      test: "not ok"

    myModule.getData()
      .then (response) ->
        response.json()
      .then (data) ->
        expect(data).toEqual
          test: "ok"
```

Despite the expected data not being the same as that provided, the test passes. I suspect the fetch isn't being made? Please can someone suggest how I might get this to work, or otherwise a better way to test this function? Thanks.